# JavaScript NPM Error in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

In visual Studio Code , i want my javascript program to run and automatically through a server as , i'm learning javascript through a online.

i try to did the same steps as i watched a tutorial on Setup IDE .

so i installed Git and Node , now when i open Visual Studio , after saving a Hello World Program , it should run automatically .

so i type in Terminal : npm install
then error came , then again i typed npm run dev to start my server in Browser.

```
i [the error in the pic is :
C:\Users\Addie\Desktop\JS\webpack-starter-master>npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Addie\Desktop\JS\webpack-starter-master\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Addie\Desktop\JS\webpack-starter-master\package.json'
npm WARN webpack-starter-master No description
npm WARN webpack-starter-master No repository field.
npm WARN webpack-starter-master No README data
npm WARN webpack-starter-master No license field.

up to date in 10.317s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

`C:\Users\Addie\Desktop\JS\webpack-starter-master>npm run dev`

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Addie\Desktop\JS\webpack-starter-master\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Addie\Desktop\JS\webpack-starter-master\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Addie\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-02T22_21_22_028Z-debug.log
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmeuZ.png)

Please help me out , what should i do and what am i doing wrong?.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `npm init` to create a `package.json` for your directory

Answer (score 0):

To run a JavaScript file locally (using node):

```
$ cd PATH_TO_PROJECT_FOLDER
$ node FILE_NAME
```

If you're trying to run a project which contains a `npm run dev` script to start up a server:

```
$ cd PATH_TO_PROJECT_FOLDER
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```